# How to use forward() method instead of model.generate() for T5 model

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

For my use case, I need to use the model.forward() instead of the model.generate() method
i.e instead of the below code

```
outs = model.model.generate(input_ids=batch['source_ids'],
                                 attention_mask=batch['source_mask'],
                                 output_scores=True,
                                 max_length=model.model_arguments.max_output_seq_length)

preds_cleaned = [model.tokenizer.decode(ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True) for ids in outs]
```

I need to use

```
model_outputs = model.model(
            input_ids=batch["source_ids"],
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],
            labels=lm_labels.to(device),
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask']
        )
logits = model_outputs.logits
softmax_logits = m(logits)
max_logits = torch.max(softmax_logits, dim=2)
```

decoding these logits gives unprocessed text that has many issues like repetition of words at the end etc.
What do I need to do to get the same result as model.generate() ?

Answer (score 12):

The two methods do something completely different.

Calling the model (which means the `forward` method) uses the `labels` for teacher forcing. This means inputs to the decoder are the `labels` shifted by one (see [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/t5.html#training)). With teacher forcing, the decoder always gets the ground-truth token in the next step, no matter what the prediction was. Teacher forcing is used from model training, all steps are fully differentiable.

When you call the `generate` method, the model is used in the autoregressive fashion. Any token it generates is put as the input in the next step. However, selecting the token is a "hard" decision, and the gradient cannot be propagated through this decision. The generate method cannot be used for training. The output is coherent because the decoder reacts to what was previously generated.

With teacher forcing, the model might want to prefer generating a token and continue consistently with the generated token. However, it cannot continue consistently, because it is forced to continue as if it generated the token that actually is in the `labels` argument. This why you observe the incoherent output (which was nevertheless never intended to be output but only to be used for training).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That explains a lot. So, essentially for my usecase, I need to use inputs_embeds instead of input_ids while generating from the T5 model. model.model() supports that but generate() method doesn't. How can I do that?

Comment: @jindrich, can you please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72177055/forward-outputs-on-multiple-sequences-is-wrong?noredirect=1#comment127536983_72177055

Comment: @jindřich does it mean that when we use a forward pass with a label it is not auto-regressive?

Answer (score 0):

This is the weirdest thing so far and cost me a few days of debugging. i think there is a bug in the T5 greedy search algorithm
During training:
The cross entropy loss becomes smaller and smaller, to the point where you do argmax(dim=2) on the logits, you get exactly the same result as the “labels”.
This means that when you feed the same input string into the model.generate(), you SHOULD get the same output.
However, the generate (inference) produce slightly different.

This is very annoying.