# Forward outputs on multiple sequences is wrong

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using `T5` to summarize multiple sequences as a batch. Here I want to generate the output of `model.generate(input_ids)` by calling `forward function` (`model(**inputs)`). I know that `forward()` and `generate()` work completely different [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67328345/2130515). To make them working the same way. I take some sequences and call `model.generate()` on them to generate the corresponding outputs and get pairs of (`text`, `summary`). Now, Calling the `forward function` on these pairs one each time generates the same outputs. However, when calling the forward function on batch of sequences, the output is not the same ? **What I missed** ?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
model.to("cuda")
model.eval()

# sequences
seq1 = "summarize: Calling the model (which means the forward method) uses the labels for teacher forcing. This means inputs to the decoder are the labels shifted by one"
output1 = "calling the model uses the labels for teacher forcing. inputs to the decoder"

seq2 = "summarize: When you call the generate method, the model is used in the autoregressive fashion"
output2 = "the model is used in the auto-aggressive fashion."

seq3 = "summarize: However, selecting the token is a hard decision, and the gradient cannot be propagated through this decision"
output3 = "the token is a hard decision, and the gradient cannot be propagated through this decision"

input_sequences = [seq1, seq2, seq3]
output_seq = [output1, output2, output3]

# encoding input and attention mask
encoding = tokenizer(
    input_sequences,
    padding="longest",
    max_length=128,
    truncation=True,
    return_tensors="pt",
)

input_ids, attention_mask = encoding.input_ids.to("cuda"), encoding.attention_mask.to("cuda")

# labels
target_encoding = tokenizer(
    output_seq, padding="longest", max_length=128, truncation=True
)
labels = target_encoding.input_ids
labels = torch.tensor(labels).to("cuda")
labels[labels == tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100

# Call the models
logits = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels).logits

# Apply softamx() and batch_decode()

X = logits
X = F.softmax(X, dim=-1)
ids = X.argmax(dim=-1)
y = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequences=ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

# results: batch_size=3

['call the model uses the labels for teacher forcing  inputs to the decoder are',
 'the model is used in the auto-aggressive fashion  the the the',
 'the token is a hard decision, and the gradient cannot be propagated through this decision ']

# results: batch_size =1 i.e. consider 1 seq each time

['call the model uses the labels for teacher forcing  inputs to the decoder are']

['the model is used in the auto-aggressive fashion ']

['the token is a hard decision, and the gradient cannot be propagated through this decision ']
```

Comment: When you feed only one sequence as input then the transformer performs attention on that sequence only, But when we input a batch of sequences (with uneven length) then attention is performed over <EOF> tokens also which could be the reason behind extra `the` in the second sequence

Comment: @KaranDhingra, thanks but even with 4 sequences, it is still the sam problem

Comment: It does not depend on number of input sequences but the <EOS> tag present. Please try it again but truncate it till the length of second sequence then your output should match of you just input second sequence

Comment: @KaranDhingra, normally this shoul be fixed by mask_attention because we pad the short sequence and we mask the pad token. Based on your thought we should train with equal length sequences!

Comment: no no, you are right. I completely forgot about the mask attention. Lemme try replicating this with pretrained transformer because the output should be same